# Update the amounts in a table by the amounts from another table when the first table is column-based and the second is row-based

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables, A and B.

A is like

| A_Policy | Value First Category | Value Second Category | Value Third Category | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15000 | 2000 | 75000 | ... |
| 11 | 12500 | 2500 | 7000 | ... |
| 12 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The amounts in the fields `Value Category X` are not correct. I would like to update these amounts thanks to table B, which is like

| B_Policy | Category | Value | ... | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 11000 | ... | ... |
| 10 | 2 | 1500 | ... | ... |
| 10 | 3 | 8500 | ... | ... |
| 11 | 1 | 12500 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can we proceed? The difficulty here comes from the fact that we have three fields for the Values in table A and only 1 field for the value in table B.

Comment: Are you always going to have fixed categories, or dynamic?  If they are going to be dynamic I'd suggest looking at how to pivot and unpivot data.  This allows you to map columns to rows and vice versa.  If these are going to be static then most efficient method will likely be to run three updates.

Comment: @MatthewBaker Yes, I only have 3 categories. Fixed...

Comment: as a side note, its also helpful when posting your data to included it as code rather than just a table.  That way people who are answering can test solutions directly.  If you have a look at my answer below, the first thing I did was create two tables, and populate the with your data.  Detail like that will make answerers lives easier and you'll be more likely to get responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this then.

```
DECLARE @table_a AS TABLE ( A_Policy INT, First INT, Second INT, Third INT )

DECLARE @table_b AS TABLE ( B_Policy INT, Cat INT, Value INT )

INSERT INTO @table_a ( A_Policy, First, Second, Third )
VALUES ( 10, 15000, 2000, 75000 )
,      ( 11, 12500, 2500, 7000 )

INSERT INTO @table_b ( B_Policy, Cat, Value )
VALUES ( 10, 1, 11000 )
,      ( 10, 2, 150 )
,      ( 10, 3, 8500 )
,      ( 11, 1, 12500 )

SELECT  *
  FROM  @table_a

UPDATE  a
   SET  First = Value
  FROM  @table_a a
  JOIN  @table_b b ON   a.A_Policy = b.B_Policy
                  AND   b.Cat = 1

UPDATE  a
   SET  Second = Value
  FROM  @table_a a
  JOIN  @table_b b ON   a.A_Policy = b.B_Policy
                  AND   b.Cat = 2

UPDATE  a
   SET  Third = Value
  FROM  @table_a a
  JOIN  @table_b b ON   a.A_Policy = b.B_Policy
                  AND   b.Cat = 3

SELECT  *
  FROM  @table_a
```

Not the most graceful approach, but if there are only three updates, in the real world this is a quick and workable solution.  Scalability will depend on how many rows you have.

Comment: thanks for your help ! I Tried to adapt your query to my problem but an error appears at the "UPDATE" line. (underlined in red) `SELECT * FROM X

UPDATE Xx 
SET Xx.D100_LIB17=Yy.GAD_CAPITAL
FROM X Xx
INNER JOIN Y Yy 
ON Xx.D100_PTRSORID = Yy.GAD_PTRSORID and Yy.GAD_CODE = '201**'

SELECT * FROM X` I don't know exactly why. The message error is "Incorrect syntax near update. Expected [...]"

Comment: Can I suggest you post your table definition, and a couple of sample rows of data. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the source table multiple times with itself to "pivot" it into the form that you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.B_Policy
              , t1.Value as Value_Category_1
              , t2.Value as Value_Category_2
              , t3.Value as Value_Category_3 
  FROM tab_b t0
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t1 ON t0.B_Policy = t1.B_Policy AND t1.category = 1   
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t2 ON t0.B_Policy = t2.B_Policy AND t2.category = 2 
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t3 ON t0.B_Policy = t3.B_Policy AND t3.category = 3 
;
```

You can then use that to `MERGE` it into your target table.

In one statement

```
WITH b_pivot AS 
  (  SELECT DISTINCT t0.B_Policy, t1.Value as Value_Category_1, t2.Value as Value_Category_2, t3.Value as Value_Category_3 
       FROM tab_b t0
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t1 ON t0.B_Policy = t1.B_Policy AND t1.category = 1   
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t2 ON t0.B_Policy = t2.B_Policy AND t2.category = 2 
  LEFT JOIN tab_b t3 ON t0.B_Policy = t3.B_Policy AND t3.category = 3 
  )
MERGE tab_a
USING b_pivot
   ON tab_a.A_Policy = b_pivot.B_Policy
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET tab_a.Value_Category_1 = COALESCE(b_pivot.Value_Category_1, tab_a.Value_Category_1),
                tab_a.Value_Category_2 = COALESCE(b_pivot.Value_Category_2, tab_a.Value_Category_2),
                tab_a.Value_Category_3 = COALESCE(b_pivot.Value_Category_3, tab_a.Value_Category_3)
;
```

Result:

| A_Policy | Value_Category_1 | Value_Category_2 | Value_Category_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11000 | 1500 | 8500 |
| 11 | 13000 | 2500 | 7000 |

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d897a7fdc2775ec914552d3d555345cf).